# Apache-style multiviews with Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite

I'm interested in switching from Apache/mod_php to Nginx for some non-CMS sites I'm running. The sites in question are either completely static HTML files or simple PHP, but the one thing they have in common is that I'm currently using Apache's mod_negotiation to serve them up without file extensions. I'm not concerned with actual content negotiation; I'm using this just so I don't have to use file extensions in my URLs.

For example, the file at `/info/contact.php` is accessed via a URL of just `/info/contact`

The actual file is a `.php` file in that location, but I don't use the extension in the URLs. This gives me slightly shorter, cleaner URLs and also doesn't expose what's essentially a meaningless implementation detail to the user. In Apache, all this takes is enabling mod_negotiation and adding +MultiViews to the Options for the site. In Nginx I gather I'll be rewriting somehow but being new to Nginx, I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

These sites are currently working fine proxied from Nginx to Apache, but I'd like to try running them solely with Nginx/fastcgi. They work fine this way as long as I'm using the extensions, so the fastcgi aspect is working great. My concern now is just with removing those extensions.

It's important to keep in mind that the filename is not *always* in the URL, in the case of subdirectories. That is,

`/foo/bar` should look for `/foo/bar.php` or `/foo/bar/index.php`

`/foo/` should look for `/foo/index.php`

Is there a simple way to achieve this with Nginx or should I stick with proxying to Apache?

Comment: Related StackOverflow discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129544/nginx-rewrite-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any tedious rewrites, [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) works perfectly for this. It's essentially only one line.

```
server {
    server_name foo.com;
    root /your/root/path;
    index index.php;

    location /
        try_files $uri.php $uri/ /notfound.html;
    }

    # Your standard PHP location and everything else is still required here.
}
```

Comment: That almost works, but not quite. That's where I ran into a wall originally; I can get this working for URLs that contain a filename (eg, /foo going to /foo.php) but I get "No input file specified" errors for directories, such as /subdir/ or even just the root of the site - the index file is not loaded. (my try_files line is exactly as you wrote it)

Comment: That's a completely separate issue that has to do with your fastcgi SCRIPT_FILENAME variable being wrong. You'll need to post your configuration file if you want help with that.

Comment: Aha! Got it. My SCRIPT_FILENAME was actually ok but I found the answer while double checking that. Adding 'fastcgi_index index.php;' fixed the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kenn Remember to accept the answer that resolved your problem, so that others know the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
```

without the `/` in front of index.php it would look for `/foo/bar/index.php` if it couldn't find `/foo/bar/somethingelse.php`. (most people have `/index.php` as the fall back, as that is normally what would work with wordpress and similar CMSes).