# Trying to use Nginx try_files to emulate Apache MultiViews

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want a request to `http://example.com/foobar` to return `http://example.com/foobar.jpg`. (Or .gif, .html, .whatever)

This is trivial to do with Apache MultiViews, and it seems like it would be equally easy in Nginx. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/211515/apache-style-multiviews-with-nginx) seems to imply that it'd be easy as `try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;` in the location block, but that doesn't work.

`try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` doesn't work, nor does `try_files $uri =404;` or `try_files $uri.* =404;` Moving it between my `location / {` block and the regexp which matches images has no effect.

Crucially, `try_files $uri.jpg =404;` *does* work, but only for .jpg files, and it throws a configuration error if I use more than one try_files rule in a location block!

The current `server {` block:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name     example.org www.example.org;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/vhosts.access.log;
        root   /srv/www/vhosts/example;
        location / {
                root   /srv/www/vhosts/example;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|es|png)$ {
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
                try_files $uri =404;
        }
}
```

Nginx version is 1.1.14.

Comment: You should be able to simply list the files to try in order: `try_files $uri.jpg $uri.gif $uri.png $uri.css $uri.js $uri/ =404`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can emulate Apache's MultiViews, by passing the various filenames to try to `try_files`.

Nginx's [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) directive does exactly what the name suggests - it tries files in the order the are specified, and if not found, will move to the next file. Typically, the last entry is a fallback that is guaranteed to work - either a named location block, or an error page.

The commonly seen parameters of `try_files`: [`$uri`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24uri) and `$uri/` really are the paths passed to nginx - with and without the trailing slash.

So, if you go to `example.com/path/to/myfile`

```
$uri = /path/to/myfile
$uri/ = /path/to/myfile/
```

With the `try_files $uri $uri/` directive, nginx will try exactly what is passed (`$uri`) - and if that file exists, will serve it, otherwise will try to find a matching directory (`$uri/`) and serve that (using whatever index you have specified).

Since the files you are trying to serve don't actually match the path in `$uri`, you need to append the extension to `$uri` for it to work:

`$uri.jpg` will match (from the above example) `myfile.jpg` - hence why only JPEGs worked when you used it.

Since you can specify multiple files to try in `try_files`, having more than one `try_files` directive doesn't really make sense - which is why it is not allowed.

In its simplest form, therefore, just list the files you want, in the order you wish to try them (e.g.):

```
try_files $uri.jpg $uri.gif $uri.png $uri.css $uri.js $uri/ =404
```

The second location block is interesting in this case. Typically, nginx will only ever process one location block - the one that matches best. However, in the case of `rewrite ... last` processing will restart and check all available location blocks. This is essentially what `try_files` amounts to - check if exists and `rewrite ... last`, the key difference being the absence of the arguments passed which are stripped by `try_files` unless explicitly added (e.g. with `$uri?$args`).